# In app subscription trial period completion notification

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I am implementing android subscription in my app. Subscription document says the app will get notified on successful payment with purchase token and other details.

Subscription i am going to add is having trial period and i would like to alert user few days before trial period completion. Document doesn't says if will return any kind of response when user purchase subscription for trial period with $0.0 cost.

If Google play doesn't notify app for the trial period expiration or on when it charge user $0.00 for trial period, how can i notify the user few days back of trial period completion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have read full document and there is nothing mentioned about this situation. If you have any back-end server(recommended in case of in-App) you can store **purchase date**(returned from google at the time of purchase) on your server and every launch you can query your server for remaining trial days and inform user.

Another way is you can use push notification instead of query your server and send notification to your user.This approach will be having advantage and disadvantage

**Advantage:** You can inform user even your app is in background.

**Disadvantage:** user can stop notification from your app.